# X-axis Mirror does not work properly

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, mirror

I'm having troubles with the x-axis mirror operation. Maybe because I moved the bones when the option was disabled and I shouldn't do it. But now,with the option enabled,the left and right bones are no longer symmetrical. I tried to delete the right bones and then I duplicated/flipped name/mirrored on the x or local axis the left bones,but it didn't work. They are again not symmetrical. What I should to do ? Check the attached video for a better understanding of the problem. Very thanks.

[x-axis mirror video](https://sendvid.com/er6bdvwe)

Comment: Mirror is working with a center point which is the object origin in this case. The origin is not centered in your video.

Comment: how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X axis mirror is mirroring along X axis considering the origin point of the object (mesh or armature) is the center of the mirror:

[image]

As your armature seems to be centered around the world center, you can

- Snap the 3D cursor to the center <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> then cursor to center
- Then transform the origin point of your armature using the menu in object mode: object/transform/origin to 3D cursor

[image]

If the world center was not the center of your armature, you can use other snapping options to place it where needed.

Comment: Hello. thanks for your help. I centered the origin point to the center of the mass of the mesh and it worked,but let's say that I want to center the mesh and the armature to the world center. how can I do that ? I tried it,but this is what happened : https://sendvid.com/dz5mxzys

Comment: OK, I though your mesh was centered on the world center... but never mind: main thing is that it is now ok for you

Comment: yes,but I would like to find an answer to the last question. I understand that it is a different question,so what should I do ? Should I start another question on BSE ?

Comment: Object and armature origins are related after the parenting. If you change the armature origin, the mesh will follow, but the mesh may also leave it's own center position (origin) this is the problem, I think, here.

Comment: what's the solution ?

Comment: Simply move them both to the center before changing the origin's position (I don't have your file details but I think it will work)

Comment: This does only work if you use an armature, but not if you try to make an armature from a single bone

Answer (score 0):

I applied the armature's rotation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> , and it fixed my problem which I've been battling for some time

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem caused by not applying the rotation of the armature.

It can be solved by applying it rotation with shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Apply it and your problem will be solved